# What force acts on a coin that has been tossed when it is half way to the top? and what force acts on it when it is at the top?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, newtonian-gravity, projectile, free-body-diagram

This is a homework question and it appears to be a misleading question. I think that the answer is gravity for both of them. The only alternative answer I have is kinetic energy half way up and potential energy at the top, but I do not think they count as forces.

Comment: Hint: what **force** acts on a coin after it has been tossed?

Comment: You are correct:  Kinetic energy and potential energy are not forces.

Comment: i don't think it's any more misleading than other questions you must have done that are worded to check your knowledge of the problem.

Comment: Strictly speaking, while the coin is on its way to the top there will be both gravity and drag - at the top it has no linear velocity so the drag goes away. If it is spinning it will still experience rotational drag (the rate of spinning slows down).

Comment: Gravity! Gravity! Gravity!

Comment: @irishphysics its misleading because if where indeed just gravity you would think they would ask one question not two.

Comment: @raykay examiners eh! I can't write anything bad about them on this forum but I can think bad about them, and I will!!

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct - in a simplistic view gravity is the only force acting on the coin once it has left the hand tossing it, regardless of whether it is halfway up or at the top of its path. You might also consider the drag force arising from interaction with the surrounding air, which is probably convenient to decompose into a linear part (for the rising and falling of the coin) and a rotational part (for the spinning).

Comment: Really just putting some of the comments into an answer here.